# Showing Service pack version of current system in flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I am able to port much of my application from Flex 35 to Flex 4.0

Next is to show my current system Operating system name (XP Pro, Vista, Linux..etc) along with the service pack level of my system on which my application is running.

I am able to show uo OS name "Windows XP" using "Capabalities.os" in Flex4.0. but not "Professional" or "Pro" exactly. But I could not find an API for showing up the service pack level.

I have to display the content in a label. I tried with Capabilities.cpuArchitecture and System.vmversion, but it shows up some other system data.

I want to show up Service pack version.

Please help.!!

Thanks,

Nitika

Answer (score 0):

Nor really sure if this is possible :(. In AIR you could use fluorine fx.